# How to reuse styled components with different base element?

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I am making some text components, and I want them all to have the same basic CSS, but with different font-sizes and different HTML elements.  Right now I have something like this:

```
const Title = styled.h2`
  font-size: 24px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 500;
`;

const Subtitle = styled.h4`
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 500;
`;

const Body = styled.p`
  font-size: 16px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 500;
`;
```

I'd like to be able to set the `color` and `font-weight` for all three in one place, but have the font-size and HTML element remain separate.  How can I do this with styled-components?

Answer (score 1):

**createGlobalStyle** might help you, please refer to the styled-components [docs](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#createglobalstyle).

```
const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
  body {
    --fontWeight: 500;
    --color: black;
  }
`
```

Then for your other styled-components which will be used in the app you can use it as follows:

```
const Title = styled.h2`
  font-size: 24px;
  color: var(--color);
  font-weight: var(--fontWeight);
`;

const Subtitle = styled.h4`
  font-size: 20px;
  color: var(--color);
  font-weight: var(--fontWeight);
`;

const Body = styled.p`
  font-size: 16px;
  color: var(--color);
  font-weight: var(--fontWeight);
`;
```

More about CSS custom properties can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties).